# How to prevent Safari from dropping the Authorization header when following a same-origin redirect?

Tags: http, browser, safari, fetch-api

Safari seems to drop the `Authorization` header when following a same-origin 301 redirect. For example, this JS code:

```
fetch("/api/endpoint-that-redirects", { headers: new Headers({ "Authorization": "sometoken" })})
```

will trigger one `GET` to `/api/endpoint-that-redirects` with the `Authorization` header, which responds with a `301` w/ Location `/api/endpoint`. The browser follows this automatically, meaning it makes another GET to `/api/endpoint`, but this time **without** the `Authorization` header.

This seems to be expected behavior when redirecting to a *different origin*, but I can't see why this would happen if the redirect is to another URL at the same origin.

I've seen a lot of posts online and questions about this behavior on StackOverflow, but I haven't seen any definitive solution or at least an explanation about this behavior. It's also not clear in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57974176/458968) if the redirect is to the same host.

Chrome (98) and Firefox (97) both follow the redirect and include the `Authorization` header in the subsequent GET request.

Comment: The Safari behavior described in the question doesn’t conform to the requirements in the Fetch spec. So it’s a bug in Safari and should be reported in the WebKit/Safari issue tracker at https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=WebKit. Would you be willing to raise an issue for it there? If not, let me know, and I can create an issue for it there myself.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, please go ahead and create the issue there. I'd rather not have to create a bugzilla account just for this purpose. Thank you!

Comment: For the record here, https://stackoverflow.com/users/9961392/lmx opened a Safari bug at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=239944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari 15.4+ (iOS 15.4, macOS 12.3) users will no longer experience this `Authorization` drop.

Details: A fix for this was actually [merged into the WebKit/Safari code back in October 2021](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/8cfdff34446111a6798d0cbcff494322fd14dd69) but per comments at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230935#c18 didn’t end up shipping until mid-March 2022 in Safari 15.4.

So, this problem will continue to happen for any users of Safari versions prior to to 15.4 — users not upgraded to iOS 15.4 or macOS 12.3 yet — but not for users with current Safari/iOS/macOS.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug per the Fetch Standard as written. See *httpRequest* in [HTTP-network-or-cache fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-network-or-cache-fetch). Each HTTP request essentially starts out with a clone from the input request, which includes all developer-set headers.

However, for the specific case of `Authorization` it is [an open issue](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/944) whether it shold be included across origins.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing that GH issue! I've upvoted your answer but not sure if I should accept until there's a solution. This behavior is breaking our API clients because we require an `Authorization` header for each request, and we have an internal redirect.