# Django Rest Framework: Unable to Retrieve Authorization Token from Header on Hosted Server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authorization

I have hosted a Django Rest Framework API on a domain. In my code, I retrieve the Authorization token from the header using the following line:

```
request.headers.get('Authorization', None)
```

This code works perfectly fine on my local server and when I run the server using python manage.py runserver with an IP address. However, when deployed on my hosted server, I'm getting None as a result.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have already added my domain to the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in Django's settings file. The server is hosted on a Linux environment.

Is there any additional configuration that I need to apply for a hosted deployment, specifically on a Linux server, to ensure that the Authorization header is correctly received?

Comment: Are you using Safari to make the requests?

Comment: The reason I asked is because this is a well known issue on Apple Safari. This issue was pointed out [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72293278/16770846)

Comment: If your client is not Apple Safari, then try other debugging approach to find out why the `Authorization` header does not reach the server.

Comment: I used POSTMAN to make an API call, and I used the Firefox browser on Windows. Is there any issue in Safari? This issue only occurs when I use my domain link. How can I use the debugger?

Comment: I printed the request header in the console and  there is no Authorization key in header in Hosted link

Comment: When deploying a Django application to a production server, especially in a Linux environment, there are a few additional considerations that might affect how headers, including the Authorisation header. Did you configure your web server to to pass the Authorisation header to your Django application?

Comment: @Temi I'm noob in servers and configuration can you give me any guide to do that

Comment: Cool, are you using an Apache or Nginx server?

Comment: You should provide more information. Your code, what api endpoint you making the call to and the information you sending to that api

Comment: @Temi i use Apache running bitnami

Comment: Can you check if your Apache has been configured to forward Authorization headers correctly.

Answer (score 1):

adding the line `WSGIPassAuthorization On` to vhost.config file is the solution to this issue. It allows the Apache server to pass the Authorization